# Query for specific columns with rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, arel

I want to run a query that only returns the columns that I specify. I haven't been able to find a good way to do this with rails 3. My first attempt was

```
query = transactions.group("month").
                     select("DATE_FORMAT(transactions.purchased_at, '%Y-%m') as month")
rows = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(query.to_sql)
```

but this also includes transactions.* in the select. I have managed to get it working like this:

```
query = transactions.group("month")
query.select_values = [
  "DATE_FORMAT(transactions.purchased_at, '%Y-%m') as month", 
  "count(*) as total"
]
rows = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(query.to_sql)
```

This seems pretty nasty though, is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand what you're looking for you can just use the `select` ARel method

```
User.select('id').where('')
=> [#<User id: 2>, #<User id: 4>....
```

Comment: Unfortunately rails still includes user.* in the sql query (rails 3.0.7)

Comment: Hmm, actually that works fine. But my original query doesn't behave that way.